# SQL - Select Distinct with multiple columns and conditions

Tags: sql

I have a set of data as shown below, how to return results with distinct Set, course_id, exercise_id and test_mode, with the condition of longest testing_name. Many thanks.

| Set | course_id | exercise_id | test_mode | testing_name | testing_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 5 | 4 | C | test(12) | 2 |
| A | 5 | 4 | C | test(12) and test(34) | 3 |
| A | 5 | 4 | P | test(22) | 2 |
| A | 5 | 4 | B | B | 5 |
| A | 3 | 20 | C | test(49) | 1 |
| A | 3 | 15 | B | B | 5 |
| B | 5 | 4 | B | B | 3 |
| B | 5 | 4 | P | test(33) and test(87) | 3 |
| B | 5 | 4 | P | test(88) | 1 |

Expected results:

| Set | course_id | exercise_id | test_mode | testing_name | testing_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 5 | 4 | C | test(12) and test(34) | 3 |
| A | 5 | 4 | P | test(22) | 2 |
| A | 5 | 4 | B | B | 5 |
| A | 3 | 20 | C | test(49) | 1 |
| A | 3 | 15 | B | B | 5 |
| B | 5 | 4 | B | B | 3 |
| B | 5 | 4 | P | test(33) and test(87) | 3 |

Comment: What is your SQL database, for example MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres ?

Comment: What if two testing names have the same maximum length?

Answer (score 0):

Use `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Set, course_id, exercise_id, test_mode
                                 ORDER BY LENGTH(testing_name) DESC) rn
                                 -- use LEN() for SQL Server
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT Set, course_id, exercise_id, test_mode, testing_name, testing_count
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```